# URL to filter posts by post meta similar to shop/?product_cat="painting"

Tags: filters, urls, archives

When on the my woocommerce shop page I can filter all the products by adding ?product_cat="painting" to the URL e.g. localhost.com/shop/?product_cat="painting".

Is there a similar there a similar way to do this for post_meta? I had a custom field called 'artists' and want to filter all the products which have the same artist ID!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you use a taxonomy instead of a custom field then a query string such as ?artist=thomas would just work.

Comment: Unfortunately all the data has already been entered so too late to create a taxonomy!

Comment: I've resorted to testing to see if the artist filter is set in the url and then running a different loop depending on that!

Answer (score 0):

@Andy Macaulay-Brook is right.

You have to use a  taxonomy  and link to it just like you do with "painting"

Comment: How would the OP use this to address this particular question?

Comment: I've edited my answer. It wasn't what he needs.

Comment: Unfortunately all the data has already been entered so too late to create a taxonomy!

Comment: I've resorted to testing to see if the artist filter is set in the url and then running a different loop depending on that!